# How to use parent args on foreach when callback is defined outside

Tags: javascript

```
var products  ['product1', 'product2', 'product3']

var color = 'blue';

function callback (product) {
   console.log(product + color)
}

function printEachProduct (products, color) {
   products.forEach(callback)

}
```

How can I have access to color param if my callback is defined outside of parent scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [currying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying), and pass the `color` as first argument.

```
var products = ['product1', 'product2', 'product3'];

var color = 'blue';

function createCallback(color) {
   return function (product) {
      console.log(product + color);
   };
}

function printEachProduct(products, color) {
   products.forEach(createCallback(color));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. `callback` must accept `color` as argument.
2. Pass a new function to `forEach` that calls `callback` with the right arguments.

```
var products  ['product1', 'product2', 'product3']

var color = 'blue';

function callback (product, color) {
   console.log(product + color)
}

function printEachProduct (products, color) {
   products.forEach(function(product) { callback(product, color); })

}
```

I assume this is just the beginning of your code because as it is there is no reason for `callback` to exist.

Comment: i'm using es5 only. I used this just as an example. I just want to define for each callback outside of parent function as a standard, instead of using keword 'function' and calling callback inside of it

Comment: Then you are out of luck. Note that the answer you accepted does the same thing as mine, the parts are just placed a bit differently.

Comment: @FelixKling Almost the same thing. With the difference being that you pass `color` and `product` to `callback` for each `product` in `products`. Whereas the curried solution only passes `color` once to `createCallback`, then passes only `product` to the resulting function for each `product` in `products`.